# Can i use a for statement to create a array that includes api data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, for-loop

I'm learning and doing a project using react hooks. It's a recipe app that uses a api from [MealDB](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52772).

In this case there are multiple ingredients, each comes from separate keys in the API such as strIngredient1 up to strIngredient20. I want to put them all in a array so i can use a map to render them all in a list. Here is a example of how it is:

```
    const { strIngredient1, strIngredient2, strIngredient3, strIngredient4,
      strIngredient5, strIngredient6, strIngredient7, strIngredient8, strIngredient9,
      strIngredient10, strIngredient11, strIngredient12, strIngredient13, strIngredient14,
      strIngredient15, strIngredient16, strIngredient17, strIngredient18, strIngredient19,
      strIngredient20 } = recipeIdState;

    const ingredientArray = [strIngredient1, strIngredient2, strIngredient3,
      strIngredient4, strIngredient5, strIngredient6,
      strIngredient7, strIngredient8, strIngredient9,
      strIngredient10, strIngredient11, strIngredient12, strIngredient13, strIngredient14,
      strIngredient15, strIngredient16, strIngredient17, strIngredient18, strIngredient19,
      strIngredient20];
    setIngredients(ingredientArray);
```

I feel like it's unecessary to use so much space to create a simple array, so my question is, can i use a for to name the values and put them in the recipeIdState variable?

I'm thinking something like:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 20, i++) {
  const { `strIngredient${i}`} = recipeIdState;
  ingredientArray.push(`strIngredient${i}`);
}
  setIngredients(ingredientArray)
```

I tried creating a simple array with multiple values using simple javascript destructuring, but i feel like it's not the best way to make a clean code.

Comment: You should be able to get a single response from your API listing all the ingredients. Then you simply do a `.forEach()` against the relevant property of that response to build out your list,

Comment: The API return is being saved in a state, then i'm using those specific ingredient keys to create a array with the value of said keys.  Since the API returns a object, how would i use forEach in this case?

Comment: inspect the returned object to see what it looks like. ctrl+shift+i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you get your API response JSON and put it in a variable of its own, call it `data`. Then you can use `filter()` on `data` to find only these keys that start with `strIngredient` and extract them into a separate array for a future use.

```
let data = {
  "strIngredient1": "apple",
  "strIngredient2": "chocolate",
  "strIngredient3": "honey",
  "strIngredient4": "carrots",
  "strCategory": "cakes",
  "strInstructions": "....",
  "strDrinkAlternate":null
};

let ingredients = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
  return key.startsWith("strIngredient");
}).reduce(function(obj, key) {
  obj[key] = jsonObject[key];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(ingredients); 
// Output: { "strIngredient1": "apple", "strIngredient2": "chocolate", "strIngredient3": "honey", "strIngredient4": "carrots" }
```

After that, of course you can do all the classic `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an array.

Comment: I had not tought of that but it makes absolute sense. Thanks.

Comment: no problem. if you found this answer the most helpful, it would be great if you'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of all property values from an object.

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
```

Or, if you want to iterate over each property you can use the [`for...in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```